# Is there some way to determine whether the context allows the use of "this"?

Tags: c++, c++11, macros, this, compile-time

Is there some way to determine whether the context allows the use of "this"?

My goal is write a generic macro, for logging, which depending on the context use "this" (for instance, for print the value of "this").

Comment: Make one version that prints `this` and one that doesn't, and use the one that does within classes and the one that doesn't outside them. AFAIK there's no way to check if a variable exists or if you're in a member function.

Comment: What is "this"? Are you sure that c/c++ are the correct tags?

Comment: @qPCR4vir In C++, "this" is a pointer to the member a function was invoked on. He didn't tag it "c/c++" but "c++" and "c++11".

Comment: Is it acceptable to detect only if we're in a member function of a class derived from a special parent class? The parent class need have no data members.

Comment: If you could declare a global `void *this;`, then you wouldn't have to worry about context, scoping would automatically choose the real this if one were relevant and the global one otherwise.  But `this` is a reserved keyword.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz is not acceptable, but I'm curious about the solution in this case.

Comment: Oh.. I see. Than... what is "logging"?

Comment: will this be injected into existing code?

Comment: @John: `this` is a keyword and therefore a reserved identifier, that's not valid.

Comment: @user1476999: Have two versions of a function, 'cont int inMember()' -- a global version that returns zero and a member version (in the base class) that returns one.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: How would you then conditionally compile the code with `this`?

Comment: @GManNickG: You can't. That's why this is impossible. See my answer.

Comment: Why don't just use two versions of the macro?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, but this solutions doesn't work for static methods, or I miss something?

Comment: @lethal-guitar, because then you must be aware of the context; it is not a big deal, but if there a way that can be avoid...

Comment: Well, I always have to be aware of this, don't I? I mean I should always know if I'm currently working on a member or on a free-standing function, I'd say? Although I see that it would be nice to have it behave "polymorphically"..

Comment: @letha-guitar When I want to print a debug message I don't want to put the function name (even if I'm definitively aware about it), because a lot of reasons. The same for "this", the main purpose is save time, and avoid silly mistakes (which force you to apply some regexpr and compile again).

Comment: @user1476999: There is no `this` in a static method. And since the function isn't static, it should correctly return `0`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, but in a static (class) method, compilers doesn't complain because the scope, since they try to call the non static class method getThis() "whitout object": http://ideone.com/ey3iDf

Answer (score 2):

Even if you could do this, you could never use it. Code must be legal even if it can never get invoked, and it wouldn't be legal to mention `this` in such a context. Consider:

```
if (this_is_legal())
   std::cout << this << std::endl;
else
   std::cout << "not in member function" << std::endl;
```

Well, this code won't compile, even if the magic `this_is_legal` worked. Because the first `std::cout` line won't compile in a context where `this` is not legal.

You could do a very ugly `const void *getThis() { return NULL; }` as a global function and `const void *getThis() { return this; }` as a member function. That would give you a function that returns `NULL` or `this`. You have to hope, relying on undefined behavior, that the `this` pointer will be unmodified in a base class with no member variables.

Comment: clearly it would be possible using templates or MS's `__if_exists` kind of thing

Comment: +1 What we really need is "get this as `void*` or null if not in member function" as a single expression to have code that works regardless, but that's circular in that it depends on the original question. So surely impossible.

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford to define a base class for debugging purposes then define global and a class member `debug` functions. The member function can use `this` while the global one can use other information and scoping rules can select the correct `debug` function.

Another way is to define two macros:

```
#define ENTER_CLASS_SCOPE
# undef IN_CLASS
# define IN_CLASS 1

#define EXIT_CLASS_SCOPE
# undef IN_CLASS
# define IN_CLASS 0
```

and have the `#define IN_CLASS 0` initially. Then you can use these macros at the top and end of `cpp` files defining member functions and check the flag in the `DEBUG` macro.

Comment: This sounds like a very clever solution to me!

Comment: Sounds like a huge maintanence headache. Much easier to differentiate between the two explicitly at the call-site; global state is bad.